# How are Modules and Components saved internally?

Tags: angular

Regarding the Angular2-Practices, it is recommended to put the declarables, which are used on multiple other Modules, into a shared one.
It is furthermore strongly recommended to not set any provider on such a shared-module.
Instead, if the shared Module has services together with declarables, a static method called forRoot should be added, which returns a ModuleWithProviders-Object and only gets called by the app-Module.
I see the reasoning behind this: Since every lazy-loaded Module has its own Dependency Injector, every subequently loaded Module would get checked for its providers and used on the lazy Module instead of an application-wide Service.
What I don't see here:

- How heavy-weighted is a Module and when is it
  created? Since the app-Module has to call the forRoot-Method, the
  Module is loaded just for injecting the providers. Is the cost of this really that much better than having several instances of Services, which should be stateless anyway? I didn't find any information regarding Modules and how big they should be, especially since creating only one shared Module is not feasible, since every consuming Module would import everything from it.
- Why does the Angular-Team even suggest to add the core-services
  Module via forRoot?
  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root
  Since this Module is referenced only by the app-Module anyway, is
  there any benefit of doing this?

Since the Angular2-Logic only scans for declarables known by the Module, the comon sense would tell us to make smaller, compact shared Modules. Yet, since almost every Module has services and therefore has to be loaded by the app-Module AND each consumer, there has to be some sort of trade-off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Services often are not stateless, they are often used to share state between components, and if it's only a shared observable that one component or services uses to send events to another.
  There is **does** matter if there is one or more instances.

Modules are very lightweight. The `forRoot()` in a lazy loaded module only registers providers eagerly, the rest of the module is still lazy.

- I don't know about the reasons for the suggestions `forRoot()` in `CoreModule`.

Comment: Many thanks, regarding the Modules: A shared-Module, which is used by lazy-loaded one is eager (due to forRoot) and lazy. Is there a possibility to find out what exactly is evaluated, when a Module is imported on way?

Comment: AFAIK `forRoot()` only imports the part that is provided by the `forRoot()` implementation, not the whole module. Not sure what you mean with "what exactly is imported" or "when a Module is imported". You can add a constructor to your modules class and add a `console.log()`. Most relevant stuff is done by AoT (ahead of time compilation).

Comment: Thanks, so I think my assessment regarding smaller shared modules was correct. I'd wish the angular-team would explain a bit more regarding the structure of bigger projects, not just one feature, one sharede tc.

Comment: I think that depends a lot on what kind of application you build. For some application one strategy might be better than for another app.

Comment: Hm, just to ask, when would you suggest bigger Modules instead of smaller one?

Comment: For internal applications with fast network for example I think it would make more sense to make bigger modules that load bigger chunks of the application, while for outside users that are likely to use mobile devices it might be advantageous to only deliver what is actually used. This might cause many requests though with also could cause lags. You'd need to experiment yourself and do benchmarks to figure out what's best for your use case.

Comment: I would prefer smaller modules. It's easy to combine them into a bigger module (just create a new module that exports smaller feature modules), but it's difficult to split big modules later.